# It's not a word

Tags: riddle

Cut me in half and I am nothing.
Turn me on my side and I am everything.
What am I?

Hint:

> Look at the title.

If you still can't solve it, then here's another hint:

> It's a number!

Comment: I looked at the number of upvotes of this post, and that's how I got the answer. But in time, that number will $+1$ hahah (sorry @tox123). DVL13 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you

> 8

Cut me in half and I am nothing.

> 0

Turn me on my side and I am everything.

> Infinity

P.S. Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: cannot vote, at 8 right now.